# How do I allow insecure requests in k6s?

Tags: k6

Having an application that runs with an insecure certificate results in an error from k6.

> time="2017-11-29T14:15:16Z" level=warning msg="Request Failed" error="Put https://xxxxxxx: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to add the `insecureSkipTLSVerify: true` in options or add the `--insecure-skip-tls-verify` flag.

https://docs.k6.io/docs/options